# I am trying to fetch image from database using the Laravel framework but it only gives me the name of the image

Tags: laravel, image, upload

I am fetching the image from the database using Laravel.

In my database I am storing my image as `D:\LaravelProjects\PortfolioBuilder\public\images\6403e762461ab_.jpg`

I have tried fetching the image in this way, please check the image row:
[image: html]

I've got this result, result of the above blade file code: [image: dashboard result]

Comment: It is as easy as checking what URL it is trying to load... check the browser console and see what URL is it trying to load...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the image data is typically stored on the file system or in cloud storage.

To display the image in your application asset helper function generates a URL based on the **APP_URL** configuration value in your **.env** file. If you need to generate a URL to an image stored on a different domain or CDN, you can use the url helper function instead of asset